# Extract Top 10 products from a Excel Database (Multiple criteria)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a database (example attached) that gets updated automatically from other 70 files on monthly bases by macro.

I would like to extract Top 10 ordered products based on various criteria.(example attached) *The file will be more complex, just tried to keep it simple for demo.*

I have used some formula `=LARGE('Part numbers'!A3:A301,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS('Part numbers'!A3:A301))))` & `=SUMPRODUCT((Combine!B1:B10000='DATA '!Y3)*(Combine!C1:AB1=A1)*(Combine!D1:D10000=AC2),Combine!C1:AB10000)`that aloud me tho get the SUM of top5 products the problem is when I use the `INDEX MATCH` to extract the name of the product if there are 2 same values the formula is stooping always at the first product name + I need to add a new criteria witch is the `month`

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

*Its ok if it is macro or formula*

[image: Database image].

[image: List with criteria image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying fixing the range by making reference using the `INDIRECT`-function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("Combine!$B$1:$B$5000")='DATA '!Y3)*(Combine!$C$1:$AB$1=$C$1)*(INDIRECT("Combine!$D$1:$D$5000")=$AC$2),INDIRECT("Combine!$C$1:$AB$5000"))
```

This ensures that the Range you are referencing, e.g. `$B$1:$B$5000` doesn't become `$B$1:$B$4999` when for example Row 2 is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the pivot-table can help u?
there some autofilters to show the top x
if u want to set a dynamic filter on pivot table u can use this:

```
Sub UpdateFilter()
Dim m As String
m = Month(Now())
[filPivot] = m
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ron, yes I tried the pivot-table before, my only problem with pivot-tables is that is slowing down the Update of the file from 1 min to 15 min. Still not sure that that was the problem but as soon I deleted the PT the file started to work normaly again.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved more less.
The other problem that I have now is with the formula `=SUMPRODUCT((Combine!$B$1:$B$5000='DATA '!Y3)*(Combine!$C$1:$AB$1=$C$1)*(Combine!$D$1:$D$5000=$AC$2),Combine!$C$1:$AB$5000)` initially I have the range of the formula **=5000** but every time when my database is updated this number is decreasing till it reaches **=10**.

My database is updated by a macro that deletes Blanks every time,I believe this could be the issue.

Any ideas how to make this **=5000** range steady?